# How to extract Javascript code block from ajax reponse with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to extract Javascript code block from ajax reponse with jquery?
beside other tags(in this case div tag)
not excute or eval javascript code,

in get_js.html

```
<script> 
    $(function(){
       $.get('src.php',function(Source) {
         // In Here I want to get Javscript Code Block from string(Source)
         // Only javascript code block, not other tags
         var Code = GET_SCRIPT(Source);
         $('#code_block').val(Code);
    });
</script>
<textarea id="code_block">
</textarea>
```

in src.php

```
echo '<script>alert("this is script code, which is not to be excuted")</script><div>Blah..Blah..</div>';
```

Comment: in your `php` you should not use single quotes within single quotes. Try double.
`echo '<script>alert("this is script code, which is not to be excuted")</script><div>Blah..Blah..</div>';`

Comment: This depends, sometimes the head section and script tags will be removed when requested with ajax. Console log Source to see that the script tag is there, then just filter it out with DOM methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by simple string splitting:

```
var str = "<script>alert('this is script code, which is not to be excuted')</script><div>Blah";
var script = str.substring(str.indexOf('<script>')+8, str.lastIndexOf("</script>"));
console.log(script);
```

Above code gives:

```
alert('this is script code, which is not to be excuted')
```

The problem arises when you have several scripts in your response. But you can handle that similarly

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<textarea id="code_block"></textarea>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax('src.php').success(function(resp) {
        var $container = $('<div />'), // container element for freeform response block
            $script, script;
        $container.append(resp); // add the response content to the container so you can search it

        $script = $container.find('script'); // Locate the script block
        script = $script.html(); // Get the text only

        $('#code_block').val(script);
    });
</script>
```

I broke down the code so I could explain each step; it could be more concise. Note that this would only work for a single script block. If there were many you'd need to do some looping instead of just calling $script.text().

Comment: this doesn't works. because jQuery eval(script) when jQuery.fn.append works.

Comment: On which browser did you see this behavior? The code should not execute because the $container div is not attached to the DOM.